# Creating Python Scripts from within ArcGIS?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I used to use SAGA GIS and automated simple tasks by dragging and dropping (or clicking something and copy and paste - don't recall sorry) to create a simple script that I could then run.  I've used this for example to mosaik a bunch of files and save as a new file.  I can then just update the list of files I want to mosaik and run the script.

I am working with a team who uses ArcGIS and was hoping that there was a simple way to automate simple tasks.  I know that you can use Python with ArcGIS, and I'm looking for an easy way to help them get started along the Python path.

I don't have access to ArcGIS itself yet, so can't just play and see.  I've checked out quite a few sites on this, but they focus on more advanced tasks.

I am somewhat guessing at the version being used - but it's a new system so I presume the most recent.

Comment: I like your optimistic view, that one can start with automating task before learning basics. Good luck.

Comment: You could have a crack at model builder http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w00000001000000, it's pretty visual with all drag 'n drop controls... IMO it gets annoying when you try to iterate, that's why I learned python. If you want to know the ArcGIS version look at help:about (assuming you have a window open, Catalog or Map, doesn't matter).

Comment: @FelixIP not quite sure what you mean - I'm wanting to help them with the basics OF automating.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson - I'll look into it further.  My understanding was that you couldn't convert from Model Builder to a script as such - so this would rather limit what tasks are able to be done.  Am I correct there?

Comment: When you create a model and have tested it you can export to python script... after a while though you'll probably find it easier just to write your own script from the beginning. Get a **good** editor though, I use PyWin for python but have also tried Notepad++ which isn't too bad, mostly though I use Notepad++ for header files and XML. Another recommendation is to bookmark the Esri help in your internet browser, it's not cheating to copy and paste but it *certainly* avoids spelling mistakes.

Comment: When I said basics I meant basics of specific software. For example when I typed "mosaic" in Tools-Search (do you know where this is?) I 've got over 20 matches. Will you be able to tell which one you need without some experience? I think I am fluent with ArcGIS and decided to give it a go with QGIS and gave up after 2 days, because I got frustrated to what looked like no logic interface. If someone would ask me now to automate their QGIS workflow, I'd never say yes. Unless of course you are GIS genius an/or work in some sort of academic environment without dead line, deliverables etc..

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson - that is exactly the capability I am looking for.

Comment: @FelixIP - the people I am working with are experts in what they are doing, they know exactly what tools they use and how to do it.  What they are new to is any sort of scripting, so I was looking for an easy way to start down this path.  I can do it in SAGA, and I was hoping that there was a way for them to do this in ArcGIS - and by the looks of it there is!